# How do I programmatically validate a cypher query in Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Is there any way to use the Java API to validate a Neo4J Cypher query programmatically?

Comment: You can simply add "EXPLAIN" in the beginning of the cypher query and execute it.

Comment: I specifically asked for "programmatic", not a call to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon this thread, the compilation of cypher is handled by scala:

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/14amay53ch/cypher-grammar-file

The link on that thread is out of date, so heres the latest on github:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.1/community/cypher/cypher-compiler-3.1/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v3_1/CypherCompiler.scala

Beyond that you're on your own - @stdob comment about using EXPLAIN is still your best bet in my opinion (and should be submitted as an answer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to find `CypherParser` that `CypherCompiler` uses and created a Scala Macro that does compile-time validation of cypher queries: https://github.com/outr/neo4akka/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/outr/neo4akka/Macros.scala#L32